# Classe variável

Tags: php, html

Tenho um loop de conteúdo em Wordpress e dentro desse loop eu postei uma galeria (também padrão do WP):

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Que gera o seguinte HTML:

```
<dl class="gallery-item">
    <dt class="portrait">
        <img src=".../foto03-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail">
    </dt>
</dl>
<dl class="gallery-item">
    ...
</dl>
```

A galeria tem 11 imagens, preciso que cada uma delas tenha uma classe específica.
Ex.: Onde está escrito `class="gallery-item"` preciso que seja `class="gallery-item1"`, `class="gallery-item2"` e assim por diante.

Comment: Crie uma lista dessa classe aonde dentro da classe tenha um identificador de cada classe

Comment: @EduardoSully Editei sua pergunta, adicionando (quase sem alterações) o texto do seu comentário. Obviamente, você é capaz de escrever uma pergunta de forma clara e simples. Quando as pessoas te pedem mais detalhes, não estão sendo chatas, mas sim querendo entender melhor o **seu** problema, de forma a **te ajudar**. Quanto mais clara a sua pergunta, maiores as chances de conseguir uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

No arquivo `/wp-includes/media.php`, procure este trecho:

```
$output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
$output .= "
    <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
        $image_output
    </{$icontag}>";
```

E adicione `-{$id}` ao final do noma da classe. Dessa forma:

```
$output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
$output .= "
    <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon-{$id} {$orientation}'>
        $image_output
    </{$icontag}>";
```

Isso faz com que a posição da imagem na galeria seja utilizada no nome da classe.